# merg or combine two array in one + cakephp condition

Tags: php, cakephp

How to print this array:

```
array
      0 => 
        array
          'Shift.name LIKE' => string '%Burberry%' (length=10)
      1 => 
        array
          'Shift.name LIKE' => string '%Butchery%' (length=10)
```

like this:

```
array 
  'Shift.name LIKE' => string '%Burberry%' (length=10)  
  'Shift.name LIKE' => string '%Butchery%' (length=10)
```

what I wrote so far:

```
$skillAux =array(); $i=0;
foreach ($skillNames as $name){
                    $skillAux[$i] = array('Shift.name LIKE'=>'%'.$name.'%');
                    $i++;                
                }
```

Comment: Where is the $i variable coming from? There's no initiation of it.

Comment: I don't think you can make an array like that because you have the same key for two different entries.

Comment: I tried array_values() didn't work.

Comment: I am writing an OR condition in cakephp I need to wrp it in one array

Comment: @VahidRajaei please can you provide the SQL you wish to recreate with CakePHP's ORM magic? e.g. `SELECT * FROM Shift WHERE Shift.name LIKE "john" OR Shift.name LIKE "jane"`?

Comment: How ever even this works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Array keys (indexes) must be *unique*

First of all, 'keys' in an (associative) should be *unique*, so trying to achieve this;

```
array (
  'Shift.name LIKE' => '%Burberry%'  
  'Shift.name LIKE' => '%Butchery%'
)
```

Is the same as trying to do this;

```
$myArray = array();

$myArray['Shift.name LIKE'] = '%Burberry%';
$myArray['Shift.name LIKE'] = '%Butchery%';
```

In other words, you are **overwriting** the previous value for the 'Shift.name LIKE' key, so you'll end up with only the last value;

```
var_dump($myArray);

//The last value has overwritten the previous one, so you'll 
//only have 1 value in the array:
array(
    'Shift.name LIKE' string '%Butchery%' (length=10)
)
```

### Creating an 'OR' condition for *different* fields in CakePHP

You probably got confused, because when creating an 'OR' condition for *different* fields, you can just do this;

```
$results = $this->Shift->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Shift.name LIKE' => '%Burberry%',
            'Shift.something' => 'something',
        ),
    ),
));
```

This will execute something like;

```
SELECT * 
FROM shifts AS Shift
WHERE Shift.name LIKE '%Burberry%' OR Shift.something = 'something';
```

But this **won't work** if you need to do this for the *same* field (as explained in the first part of my answer)

### Creating an 'OR' condition for a *single* field in CakePHP

As mentioned in one of your comments, you're trying to create an 'OR' condition for a *single field* in CakePHP.

Basically, what you need to do, is create multiple associative arrays and wrap those in an non-associative array (actually, this is what you got in your first example)

Like this;

```
array(
    'OR' => array(
        array('Shift.name LIKE' => '%Burberry%'),
        array('Shift.name LIKE' => '%Butchery%'),
    )
)
```

Which can be used like this;

```
$results = $this->Shift->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            array('Shift.name LIKE' => '%Burberry%'),
            array('Shift.name LIKE' => '%Butchery%'),
        ),
        // other conditions can be put here
        // for example 'Shift.status' => 1
    ),
));
```

This will execute something like;

```
SELECT * 
FROM shifts AS Shift
WHERE Shift.name LIKE '%Burberry%' OR Shift.name LIKE '%Butchery%';
```

### Example

To create this array programmatically; (and I have to 'guess' here, you're question is not very clear *where* those 'Burberry' and 'Butchery' words come from)

For example, someone wants to search your database for 'Shifts' that have a name containing 'Burberry' or 'Butchery'. You collect the search query from a form-field and create an 'OR' query with those words;

```
// Search-term entered by the user
// for example, obtained via $search = $this->request->query['search'];
$search      = 'Burberry Butchery';
$keywords    = explode(' ', $search);
$conditions  = array();

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    $conditions[] = array(
        'Shift.name LIKE' => '%' . $keyword . '%'
    );
}

$results = $this->Shift->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => $conditions
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping through one of the arrays you can add every value to the other array with array_push().

Comment: I tried $merge = array_merge($merge, $skillAux[$i] ) ;  inside foreach didn't work

Comment: But you dont need the $i, you just need to use your foreach loop correctly.

Comment: $merge = array_merge($merge, array('Shift.name LIKE'=>'%'.$name.'%') ) ;  didn't work

Comment: But send us your code, i think you arent using the foreach loop correctly.

Comment: $skillAux =array(); $i=0;
            $merge = array();
            foreach ($skillNames as $name){
                $skillAux[$i] = array('Shift.projects_aux LIKE'=>'%'.$name.'%');
                //$merge = array_merge( $merge, $skillAux  );
                
               $merge = array_merge($merge, array('Shift.projects_aux LIKE'=>'%'.$name.'%') ) ; 
                
                
                $i++;
                
            }
            var_dump($merge);

Comment: just rename projects_aux to name to make it clear for every one

Answer (score 0):

```
$skillAux=array();
$count=0;
foreach ($skillNames as $value){

    foreach($value as $finalkey => $finalvalue){
    echo $finalkey;
    $skillAux[$finalkey.$count] = $finalvalue;    
    }
    $count++;
}
var_dump($skillAux);exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
echo implode('<br>', $skillAux);
```

---

**Documentation**
The *implode* function will convert the entire array into a string
Syntax

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
string implode ( array $pieces )
```

1st parameter -> string of characters you want to use to join the array pieces together.

2nd parameter -> array

Compatible with  PHP 4, PHP 5

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: sorry my friend but this is completely not related to what I asked. and I don't need string. I need an array

Comment: @VahidRajaei well, you *did ask* *"How to **print** this array ... like this ..."*, so it isn't strange that Navnath came up with this answer?